# Microsoft Remote Desktop(MRD) on Mac Could not connect to Win10

Tags: macos, mac, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a Macbook Pro(With OX 10.11 EI Captain) and a ThinkPad T440p (With  Win10 TH1) in a local network, MRD  on Mac could not connect to Win10. Mac ping win OK,and User name pwd was set correct on MRD.Error Message is:Unable to connect Remote PC, MRD work well on win8.1,but not work on win10,could you help me to resolve this problem ,thanks.

Comment: RDC on Win 10 for me was a case of "switch it off then on again" then it would work from Mac. After updating to 10 it looked like it was switched on, but simply didn't work until I did that.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but it only work on wifi connection, when I disabled wireless NIC,only use wired network, it doesn't work ,even if ping each other are ok.

Comment: Then it sounds like a firewall issue. Can you please check on the Win10 box that port 3390 is open for both outbound and inbound traffic over all network types (home, work etc.)?

Comment: @cdavid I'll try it when I get home, mac book is not at hand.